# Is the usage of “that too“ grammatically OK?

Tags: usage, emphasis

> He scored 8 Bands and that too in the 1st attempt.

What does *that too* mean?

I have heard some of my friends using this.

Comment: -1 Please cite your source. The sentence is quite awkward bordering ungrammatical. I believe the score, which sounds like [an IELTS one](https://www.ieltsadvantage.com/2016/02/02/ielts-scores/#:~:text=Band%208%E2%80%93%20If%20you%20get,good%20grasp%20of%20the%20language.),  should be expressed as  **He scored band 8**

Comment: @ Mari-Lou A 
-1 for your reply for even not understanding the question.

Comment: I commented asking for a source, and I pointed out that the expression "8 bands" is highly unusual, I added a reputable reference to support my observation. I wasn't attempting to answer the question. Also, in English we say we do *something [**on** your/his/her/their first attempt*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attempt#dictionary-entry-2)

Comment: your reply is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> He scored 8 Bands and **that too** in the 1st attempt.

*that* refers to his having scored 8 Bands.  The *too* suggests that there could be some prior mentions of something else achieved in the first attempt.  The long version could be

> He achieved [that something] in the first attempt.  He scored 8 Bands too in the first attempt.

Edit

More likely, *too* means something like **what's more**, to emphasise the achievement, as Neel said too in his answer.

> He scored ... and, what's more, in the 1st attempt.

Comment: Yu're right about "that", but I think it's just an emphatic use of "too" meaning "indeed" or "what's more"; as in "I did too!" It doesn't necessarily refer to a previous thing

Comment: Thanks, @Stuart F.  I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with the poster who answered prior to me. I think in this context "that too" means "on top of" or moreover. The author here is implying that scoring 8 Bands is impressive and scoring that in the first attempt is even more impressive.

Comment: Yes. "The novice archer scored a bullseye, and at the first attempt too!" _That too in the first attempt_ is not idiomatic, though.

Answer (score 0):

I would need to know the original context to be sure, but to me this looks like a dialect way of saying "He scored 8 bands, and that was only his first attempt!"

A more common way to say that (at least in my way of speaking) would be "He scored 8 bands, and on his first attempt, too!" In this context, "too" means "in addition", but there's a lot of unspoken phrasing there. What the speaker is saying is that they think it's impressive to have gotten eight, and doing that on the first try makes it even more impressive.